# Error al intentar abrir docker desktop app

Tags: windows, docker

El día de hoy intenté abrir la aplicación de docker para escritorio y obtuve este error
System.InvalidOperationException:
Failed to deploy distro docker-desktop to C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Docker\wsl\distro: exit code: -1
stdout: Recursos insuficientes en el sistema para completar el servicio solicitado.

stderr:
en Docker.ApiServices.WSL2.WslShortLivedCommandResult.LogAndThrowIfUnexpectedExitCode(String prefix, ILogger log, Int32 expectedExitCode) en C:\workspaces\stable-2.4.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\WSL2\WslCommand.cs:línea 142
en Docker.Engines.WSL2.WSL2Provisioning.d__17.MoveNext() en C:\workspaces\stable-2.4.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Desktop\Engines\WSL2\WSL2Provisioning.cs:línea 169
--- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la ubicación anterior donde se produjo la excepción ---
en System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
en Docker.Engines.WSL2.WSL2Provisioning.d__8.MoveNext() en C:\workspaces\stable-2.4.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Desktop\Engines\WSL2\WSL2Provisioning.cs:línea 78
--- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la ubicación anterior donde se produjo la excepción ---
en System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
en Docker.Engines.WSL2.LinuxWSL2Engine.d__25.MoveNext() en C:\workspaces\stable-2.4.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Desktop\Engines\WSL2\LinuxWSL2Engine.cs:línea 99
--- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la ubicación anterior donde se produjo la excepción ---
en System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
en Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.TaskExtensions.d__0.MoveNext() en C:\workspaces\stable-2.4.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\TaskExtensions.cs:línea 29
--- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la ubicación anterior donde se produjo la excepción ---
en System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
en Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.StartTransition.d__5.MoveNext() en C:\workspaces\stable-2.4.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\StartTransition.cs:línea 67
--- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la ubicación anterior donde se produjo la excepción ---
en System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
en Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.StartTrans

No sé por qué se a producido si hasta hace poco la app abría común y corriente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He podido corregir mi error, lo que hice fue desinstalar docker y el wsl_update posterior a ello reinicié mi p, volví instalar docker pero esta vez en el menú de instalación no seleccione la opción de wls, posterior instalé wsl update otra vez y quedó funcionando